# Why is anaconda not found in conda install?

Tags: anaconda

I am getting the following error:

```
$ conda create -n myenv anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - anaconda
```

This is the default conda that comes with Amazon Linux.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

How can I fix this?